# Permission Denied when trying to Install Anaconda Public GPG Key to the Trusted Store

Tags: apt, permissions, sudo, gnupg

**Context:**
I'm setting up JupyterHub on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I'm trying to install the Anaconda Public GPG Key to Trusted Store via the following command:

`curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/gpgkeys/anaconda.asc | gpg --dearmor > conda.gpg`
but when I do, I get the following `Permission Denied` error: `curl: (23) Failed writing body`

**Attempted Solution:**
I tried adding `sudo` to the start of the command but it still gives me the same error.

**Question:**
How do I get this command to run?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: The command will not have permissions unless run unless it's run from a directory that has the correct permissions.

Running the command from the home directory (get there via `cd ~`) will work.